# Why don't we count linear search cost as a prerequisite bottleneck for the insertion operation of a linked list, compared to ArrayList?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, linked-list

I have had this question for a while but I have been unsatisfied with the answers because the distinctions appear to be arbitrary and more like conventional wisdom that is sort of blindly accepted rather than assessed critically.

In an ArrayList it is said that insertion cost (for a single element) is linear. If we are inserting at index p for 0 <= p < n where n is the size of the list, then the remaining n-p elements are shifted over first before the new element is copied into position p.

In a LinkedList, it is said that insertion cost (for a single element) is constant. For instance if we already have a node and we want to insert after it, we rearrange some pointers and it's done quickly. But getting this node in the first place, I don't see how it can be done other than a linear search first (assuming it isn't a trivial case like prepending at the start of the list or appending at the end).

And yet in the case of the LinkedList, we don't count that initial search time. To me this is confusing because it's sort of like saying "The ice cream is free... after you pay for it." It's like, well, of course it is... but that sort of skips the hard part of paying for it. Of course inserting in a LinkedList is going to be constant time if you already have the node you want, but getting that node in the first place may take some extra time! I could easily say that inserting in an ArrayList is constant time... after I move the remaining n-p elements.

So I don't understand why this distinction is made for one but not the other. You could argue that insertion is considered constant for LinkedLists because of the cases where you insert at the front or back where linear time operations are not required, whereas in an ArrayList, insertion requires copying of the suffix array after position p, but I could easily counter that by saying if we insert at the back of an ArrayList, it is amortized constant time and doesn't require extra copying in most cases unless we reach capacity.

In other words we separate the linear stuff from the constant stuff for LinkedList, but we don't separate them for the ArrayList, even though in both cases, the linear operations may not be invoked or not invoked.

So why do we consider them separate for LinkedList and not for ArrayList? Or are they only being defined here in the context where LinkedList is overwhelmingly used for head/tail appends and prepends as opposed to elements in the middle?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124828/discussion-on-question-by-sean-hill-why-dont-we-count-linear-search-cost-as-a-p).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using a LinkedList, chances are you're not going to use it for a random access insert.  LinkedList offers constant time for push (insert at the beginning) or add (because it has a ref to the final element IIRC).  You are correct in your suspicion that an insert into a random index (e.g. insert sorted) will take linear time - not constant.

ArrayList, by contrast, is **worst case** linear.  Most of the time it simply does an arraycopy to shift the indices (which is a low-level shift that is constant time).  Only when you need to resize the backing array will it take linear time.

Comment: Where do you get that `System.arraycopy` is "a low-level shift that is constant time"? It's _low level_ in that it's implemented as an intrinsic, but it fully copies every byte from the source to the destination, and is most definitely **not** constant time: it takes time roughly proportional to the number of elements copied (with some discontinuities in performance as you exceed the size of various cache levels). So inserting at the front of an ArrayList is always going to be an `O(n)` operation.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I recall that being claimed in a lecture that simply shifting an existing memory block (like a memcpy in C) was constant... but on further review it looks like I should have looked into it further.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a limitation of the Java interface for `List` and `LinkedList`, rather than a fundamental limitation of linked lists. That is, in Java there is no convenient concept of "a pointer to a list node".

Every type of list has a few different concepts loosely associated with the idea of pointing to a particular item:

- The idea of a "reference" to a specific item in a list
- The integer position of an item in the list
- The value of a item that may be in the list (possibly multiple times)

The most general concept is the first one, and is usually encapsulated in the idea of an *iterator*. As it happens, the simple way to implement an iterator for an array backed list is simply to wrap an integer which refers to the position of the item in a list. So for array lists only, the first and second ways of referring to items are pretty tightly bound.

For other list types, however, and even for most other container types (trees, hashes, etc) that is *not* the case. The generic reference to an item is usually something like a pointer to the wrapper structure around one item (e.g., `HashMap.Entry` or `LinkedList.Entry`). For these structures the idea of accessing the *nth* element isn't necessary natural or even possible (e.g., unordered collections like sets and many hash maps).

Perhaps unfortunately, Java made the idea of getting an item by its *index* a first-class operation. Many of the operations directly on `List` objects are implemented in terms of list indexes: `remove(int index)`, `add(int index, ...)`, `get(int index)`, etc. So it's kind of natural to think of those operations as being the fundamental ones.

For `LinkedList` though it's more fundamental to use a pointer to a node to refer to an object. Rather than passing around a list index, you'd pass around the pointer. After inserting an element, you'd get a pointer to the element.

In C++ this concept is embodied in the concept of the `iterator`, which is the first class way to refer to items in collections, including lists. So does such a "pointer" exist in Java? It sure does - it's the `Iterator` object! Usually you think of an `Iterator` as being for iteration, but you can also think of it as pointing to a particular object.

So the key observation is: given an pointer (iterator) to an object, you can remove and add from linked lists in *constant time*, but from an array-like list this takes *linear time* in general. There is no inherent need to *search* for an object before deleting it: there are plenty of scenarios where you can maintain or take as input such a reference, or where you are processing the entire list, and here the constant time deletion of linked lists does change the algorithmic complexity.

Of course, if you need to do something like *delete the first entry containing the value "foo"* that implies both a search *and* a delete operation. Both array-based and linked lists taken `O(n)` for search, so they don't vary here - but you can meaningfully separate the *search* and *delete* operations.

So you could, in principle, pass around `Iterator` objects rather than list indexes or object values - at least if your use case supports it. However, at the top I said that "Java has no convenient notion of a pointer to a list node". Why?

Well because actually using `Iterator` is actually very inconvenient. First of all, it's tough to get an `Iterator` to an object in the first place: for example, and unlike C++, the `add()` methods don't return an Iterator - so to get a pointer to the item you just added, you need to go ahead and iterate over the list or use the `listIterator(int index)` call, which is inherently inefficient for linked lists. Many methods (e.g., `subList()`) support only a version that takes indexes, but not Iterators - even when such a method could be efficiently supported.

Add to that the restrictions around iterator invalidation when the list is modified, and they actually become pretty useless for referring to elements except in immutable lists.

So Java's support of pointers to list elements is pretty half-hearted an so it's tough to leverage the constant time operations that linked list offers, except in cases such as adding to the front of a list, or deleting items during iteration.

It's not limited to lists, either - the `ConcurrentQueue` is also a linked structure which supports constant time deletes, but you can't [reliably use that ability from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226759/efficiently-removing-an-element-added-to-a-concurrentqueue).